# Python: Pentagonal number function confusion

Tags: python, function, math

I keep getting

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

in my program.

The purpose of this program is to list all the Pentagonal Numbers from 1 to 100, doing 10 per line. So far I have this:

```
def getPentagonalNumber(n):
    p = n(3*n-1) // 2
    print(p)

def printPentagonalNumber(numberOfPentagonal):
    number_of_Pentagonal = 100
    NUMBER_OF_PENTAGONAL_PER_LINE = 10
    count = 0
    n = 1

    while count < numberOfPentagonal:
        if getPentagonalNumber(n):
            count += 1 # increase count

            if count % NUMBER_OF_PENTAGONAL_PER_LINE == 0:
                print()

        n =+1

def main():
    print("The first 100 pentagonal numbers are")
    printPentagonalNumber(100)

main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `p=n(3*n-1) // 2` to do?

Comment: It looks like you left out the `*` between `n` and `(3*n-1)`. Or did you think that `n(3*n-1)` would multiply `n` by `(3*n-1)`? It doesn't do that. `n(stuff)` attempts to call a function named `n`. But in your code `n` is an integer, not a function.

Comment: As Tim said, there are certain other things that are not correct in your code. Eg, `if getPentagonalNumber(n)` will **never** be true. Can you see why?

Comment: I continue to just get one for the output, please explain.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to this line:

```
p = n(3*n-1) // 2
```

Python does not implicitly do multiplication.
Instead, you have to use:

```
p = n*(3*n-1) // 2
```

However, there are certain other things that are not correct in your code. Let us know if you need further help.